# $_SESSION from different server

Tags: php, session, cookies

www.example.com/index.php have:

```
        <?   
        session_start(); 
        ?>
    $_SESSION['user']= $username;  
'<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=www.different.com/test.php">';
```

www.different.com/test.php is:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 die ("Access Denied");
}
?>
```

I get error "Access Denied". How session user different page? I think is bad coockies?

Comment: Sessions are unique to each server. You can't access them nor export them from one server to another. Plus, for argument's sake, `$_SESSION['user']= $username;` in your first body of code is outside of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Session-variables are saved on the serverside - not on the client, so the host different.com will not be able to access the variables from example.com in general.

There us a special case: if both hosts are on the same server (virtual hosts) you could try sharing the session by sending the sessionid and using `session_id($sessionid)` before `session_start()`, but I would not expect the both hosts to be on the same server.

Maybe you want to do a search for "Single-Sign-On" or "SSO" if you are trying to implement something like this.